# ¿Cómo condicionar dentro de un forech en laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel

estoy mostrando una tabla en mi proyecto de laravel y hay algunos campos que lo tengo vacio y no quiero que se muestre en blanco, así que condiciono dentro de mi forech para que me muestre un mensaje, pero de que manera puedo declarar la variable? porque lo hago así:

```
 @foreach ($productos as $item)
                                        {{ $marca = $item->marca_producto }} //este se repite
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $item->nombre_categoria }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $item->id_sub_categoria }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $item->nombre_producto }}</td>
                                            @if ($marca == null)
                                                <td><b>PENDIENTE</b></td>
                                            @else
                                            <td>{{ $item->marca_producto }}</td>
                                            @endif
                                            <td>{{ $item->pack_producto }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $item->origen_producto }}</td>
                                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i
                                                        class="fa fa-ban"></i></button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
```

No quiero que me muestre la variable así como en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes facilmente comprobar si `$item->marca_producto` es distinto de null y esta definida

```php
@foreach ($productos as $item)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $item->nombre_categoria }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->id_sub_categoria }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->nombre_producto }}</td>

   @if (! isset($item->marca_producto) )
        <td><b>PENDIENTE</b></td>
   @else
        <td>{{ $item->marca_producto }}</td>
   @endif
   <td>{{ $item->pack_producto }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item->origen_producto }}</td>
   <td>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
           <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
       </button>
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Esto debería de funcionar para ti; lo que te esta pasando es que estas usando `{{ }}` las sintaxis de mostacho para declarar la variable, lo que quiere decir que no solo la estas declarando, sino también interpolando en la plantilla, alternativamente puedes declarar un bloque `@php`:

```php
@php
    $marca = $item->marca_producto;
@endphp
```

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres mostrar el mensaje "PENDIENTE" por cada producto que recorras y que no tenga marca de producto, puedes utilizar el [operador de fusión null](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/05/21/operador-fusion-null-coalesce-php/)

Solo tendrías que poner algo como lo siguiente:

```
<td> {{ $item->marca_producto ?? 'PENDIENTE' }} </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de la siguiente forma:

```
{{ $item->nombre_categoria ?? 'Sin categoría'}}
```

M